# In Django Rest Framework how to update FK in serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add a vote functionality to the code found in [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#tutorial) of Django Rest Framework. On top of Snippet model, I added a Vote model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    snippet = models.ForeignKey(Snippet, related_name='votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

After posting and validating a user vote to a snippet, I now want to update the number of votes received by the snippet (I added to the Snippet model a number_of_votes field).

I'm doing it in the create method of my VoteSerializer like that:

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    voter = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='voter.username',validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=VoteUp.objects.all(), message=already_voted)])
    snippet = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Snippet.objects.all())

    def validate(self, data):
        # ... my validation function

    def create(self, validated_data):
        obj = Vote.objects.create(**validated_data)
        obj.snippet.number_of_votes += 1
        obj.snippet.save()
        return obj
```

It works well but I'm not sure if it's the good way or not to do it. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. But I am wondering why are you keeping count of votes. You can just have snippet id in each vote that is associated with the snippet and simply do a count over it to get the number.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `number_of_votes` variable? If all you want to do is know how many votes each snippet has, you should be able to do that just from the queryset made from the foreign keys. `snippet.vote_set.count()` should return the number of votes that have a foreign key relation to `snippet`

Comment: I thought that it's maybe more efficient to keep a count so if many users want to view the page of snippets ordered by descending number of votes, the calculation is done once only.

Comment: Then if I were you I would handle it either in a `post_save` signal on `Vote` creation or just overwrite `Vote.save` and have it increment the associated count variable. You typically don't want to make changes in serializers since that's not exactly expected behavior during serialization. I can provide an answer with an example if you need it.

Comment: Thanks @MCBama. Your example or any link will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of possible "better" ways to try:

**Overwrite Save Method**

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    snippet = models.ForeignKey(Snippet, related_name='votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # ensure model is being created and not just modified:
    if not self.pk:
      # increment snippet vote counter
      self.snippet.number_of_votes += 1
      self.snippet.save()

    # call base save method to ensure proper handling
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Use a Post Save signal**

Once you have signals setup for your Django project following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/) you can create a signal that will look something like this:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
# make sure you import Vote here. I'm not sure of your project 
# setup so I can't write the import for you.

@receiver(post_save, sender=Vote)
def update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  # only increment on model creation
  if created:
    instance.snippet.number_of_votes += 1
    instance.snippet.save()
```

Although in all honesty I'm pretty sure `snippet.vote_set.count()` is a pretty fast call and shouldn't interfere with your run time any if you wanted to start by using that instead of a counter. Because remember if you increment the counter you're going to have to decrement it too or your count will be off if someone deletes a record.